# Expansion file stopped working when update apk

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

Recently updated an APK and chose the option to reuse the expansion file (with videos).

**Old version**

```
1(1.0.0) -> main.1.br.com.myapp.obb
```

**New version**

```
2(1.0.1) -> selected the same
```

The application has been updated and usually recognized the file expansion.
But when you play the video the following error occurs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12752): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12752): at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APEZProvider.openAssetFile(APEZProvider.java:182)
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

Was necessary to add the tags `<meta -data>` in AndroidManifest to inform the version of OBB file.

```
<provider
    android:name="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:authorities="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data android:name="mainVersion" android:value="1"></meta-data>
    <meta-data android:name="patchVersion" android:value="2"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

In this [LINK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31107/arquivo-de-expans%C3%A3o-parou-de-funcionar-quando-atualizou-vers%C3%A3o-do-apk) , the person who helped me, explain better.